# Gnuplot: close pm3d surfaces with depthorder enabled

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot a surface where each face has a different pm3d style. I tried the following:

```
reset
set format x "%.6f"
set format y "%.6f"
set format z "%.6f"
set xrange[-10:10]
set xtics border -10,5,10
set yrange[-10:10]
set ytics border -10,5,10
set cbrange[0:2]
set pm3d depthorder
set palette defined (0 'green', 1 'red', 1 'blue', 2 'black')
splot "pm3d1_1.dat" using 1:2:3:($3/200) with pm3d, "pm3d1_1.dat" using 1:2:($3-1):($3/200+1) with pm3d
```

where 'pm3d1_1.dat' is the function z=x*x+y*y with z varying between 0 and 200 (x,y between -10 and 10). The problem is that the output doesn't look how I expected when viewed from certain points of view, like this one:

[image]

I'd appreciate any help and I'd like to know if there is an alternative to plot a surface with different pm3d styles on each face. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it has to with the way `depthorder` sorts the quadrangles. Don't know if this could be fixed. To extend your question, here is an example without external data file, which also shows the problem:

```
set xrange[-10:10]
set yrange[-10:10]
set zrange[-1:200]
set isosamples 20
set pm3d depthorder
set ticslevel 0
set view 65,28
set palette defined (0 'green', 1 'red', 1 'blue', 2 'black')
splot '++' using 1:2:(z=$1**2+$2**2):(z/200.0) w pm3d,\
      '++' using 1:2:(z=$1**2+$2**2, z-1):(z/200.0+1) w pm3d
```

Result (with 4.6.4):

[image]

Don't know of any other way to plot this. Maybe I'll submit the above script as bug report.